# Listbox DataSource not working when added to a ToolStripDropDown

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripdropdown

I have been struggling all day with this problem, although I couldn't find a solution. I apologize for the long post, I tried to be concise  and clear.

**This is what works**: I create a `Form` and inside its class I create a `ListBox` dynamically and set its `DataSource` to a `DataTable` as follows:

```
public partial class FrmAddress : Form
{
    private ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();

    public FrmAddress()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        [...]

        this.Controls.Add(listBox1);
    }

    [...]

    private void Load_Countries()
    {
        this.listBox1.DataSource = dtCountries;
        this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Country";
        this.listBox1.ValueMember = "Country_ID";
    }

    [...]
}
```

**This does not work**: Create a custom control (inherited from `ToolStripDown`), create a new instance of `ToolStripControlHost(listBox1)`, add that instance to the `ToolStripDown`. Set the `listBox1.DataSource` to a `DataTable`. When `ToolStripDown` is show, the listbox is there but empty (not showing the datasource content).

```
public class CtlDropdownPopup : ToolStripDropDown
{
    ListBox controlToPop;
    ToolStripControlHost controlHost;

    public CtlDropdownPopup(ListBox controlToPop)
    {
        this.controlToPop = controlToPop;
        this.controlToPop.Location = Point.Empty;

        this.controlHost = new ToolStripControlHost(this.controlToPop);

        [...]

        this.Items.Add(this.controlHost);
    }
}

public class CtlCombobox : ComboBox
{
    private readonly CtlDropdownPopup suggestionDropDown;
    private readonly ListBox suggestionList = new ListBox();

    public CtlCombobox()
    {
        this.suggestionDropDown = new CtlDropdownPopup(this.suggestionList);
    }

    public void Source(DataTable dt, string display, string value)
    {
        this.suggestionDT = dt;

        this.suggestionList.DataSource = dt;
        this.suggestionList.DisplayMember = display;
        this.suggestionList.ValueMember = value;
    }
}
```

The custom `CtlDropdownPopup` is called like: (simplified)

```
private CtlCombobox LstCountry;
this.LstCountry.Source(dtCountries, "Country", "Country_ID");
```

As I said, the `ToolStripDropDown` is shown with the `listBox1` in it, but the list is empty. Curiously if I modify the `Source()` method to

```
    public void Source(DataTable dt, string display, string value)
    {
        this.suggestionDT = dt;

        // this.suggestionList.DataSource = dt;
        // this.suggestionList.DisplayMember = display;
        // this.suggestionList.ValueMember = value;

        if (this.suggestionList != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                this.suggestionList.Items.Add(row[display].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

The listbox is shown with the items on it. Although this workaround does the job, it is annoying not finding the answer of why can't I set the `DataSource` directly (as I did directly in the first example), but manually having to add the items.

Any ideas will really help me to sleep well tonight :)

**Thought #1:** I believe since the same `dtCountries` is linked to other `ComboBox1.DataSource`, that may be the problem, so I set `this.controlToPop.DataSource = dt.Copy();` in hopes "it is not somehow linked to the combobox", but the problem presists.

***Side note***: I am trying to create a custom combobox, that suggest items within the `DataTable`.

Idea from https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/789705/Create-combobox-with-search-and-suggest-list

Comment: `this.controlToPop.DataSource` Does this compile without casting?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed yes

Comment: Are you sure?! Because the `Control` class [doesn't have a `DataSource` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control_properties(v=vs.110).aspx). You should be getting a `'Control' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource'...` error. Same for `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`!

Comment: `Control` is the base class for all the controls of windows form but it does not have DataSource property. Only specific control have DataSource property such as DataGridView, Combobox, Listbox etc. So if you want to generalize the databinding logic using Control object, you can not do it.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed you are right. I oversimplified the code in this post, but I am setting the DataTable to the a ListBox, I updated the code.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya you are right, I oversimplified the code, although I updated the post to reflect what I have and that I am setting the Listbox DataSource property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`BindingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bindingcontext) property of the ListBox.

When a ListBox *(or any control)* is added onto the form, it inherits its `BindingContext` property from the form. Now since you're adding the ListBox onto another *TopLevel* control with `.BindingContext == null`, it doesn't inherit that property from the form, hence, it has no `BindingContext`.

You can simply avoid this problem by creating a new `BindingContext` for the ListBox:

```
public void Source(DataTable dt, string display, string value)
{
    this.suggestionDT = dt;

    this.suggestionList.BindingContext = new BindingContext();  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    this.suggestionList.DataSource = dt;
    this.suggestionList.DisplayMember = display;
    this.suggestionList.ValueMember = value;
}
```

You can also copy the `BindingContext` from the form instead *(either through the `CtlCombobox` control or by passing it as a parameter)*.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother! Now I can rest in peace. I hope you get hired by the top 3 IT companies, and if you are there already, I wish you get your salary doubled :)

Comment: You made me smile :) Glad I was able to help.